# How do i access a variable outside a file in nextjs13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

So im making an app in nextjs, I have 3 pages 1.home,2.auth,3.main

home page has a button which redirects the user to auth page where i use firebase to authorize him, after authorization i redirect the user to main page but the variable "user" conatining all info regarding user isnt available, is there a way to do this

im using nextjs13

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you should use some State Management, for example `redux`, and save the user information on it, then you can easily access the user info anywhere just like this

`const userInfo = useAppSelector((store) => store.global.userInfo)`

[Redux Doc](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: Im using createContext from react and then storing the variable in it. then im using that createContext in my _app.js where my Component tag is being covored by the createContext